# Python need to request GitHub/API/repo/statistics/contributors url twice to get content

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, github-api

I want to get particular repository's contributors and their total number of commits. I'm using Python 2.7 and Requests 2.7.0 library to request GitHub API url like: 'https://api.github.com/repos/marcboeker/mongodb-utils/stats/contributors' (This is a random link, sorry marcboeker ^_^).

However, the first time I request particular url, I got an empty dictionary response. The second time I request the same url, I can get a list that contains information I need. Here is my code:

```
import requests

contributors_url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/marcboeker/mongodb-utils/stats/contributors'
contributors = requests.get(contributors_url).json()
print contributors
```

I also tried to use GitHub authentication and tried to use urllib2 library. I also tried in Python 3.4. But I got the same result.
I need to get right result the first time I request the url, not second or third time. Since other GitHub API urls works fine, please explain why it's happening to 'contributors'.

[image: First time result]

[image: Second time result]

Comment: tried ten times and it worked for me first time every time, what version of requests?

Comment: Great point! I'm now using requests 2.3.0. I could update it and try again. Did you mean you tried ten times for the same url? Does it works for another brand new url that you've never visited before? Thanks

Comment: It worked the first time I used it, try updating and see how you go,the latest is 2.7.0, tried my own link and it worked fine also

Comment: Still not works for me. I tried both python 2.7 and 3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is due to the computation that needs to occur for generating the statistics. The [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/) outlines this:

> If the data hasn’t been cached when you query a repository’s statistics, you’ll receive a `202` response; a background job is also fired to start compiling these statistics. Give the job a few moments to complete, and then submit the request again. If the job has completed, that request will receive a `200` response with the statistics in the response body.

Can you check the status code in the request to verify that it's an empty response:

`contributors_url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/marcboeker/mongodb-utils/stats/contributors'
request = requests.get(contributors_url)
print request.status_code`

I tested this with Fiddler on a fresh repository and received both the `202` status code and an empty JSON array as the response. So I think you need to check that status code and then retry the call after a delay...

Comment: First time returned 202. Second time returned 200. Your answer perfectly explained everything. I already moved to a different approach to get content I need without using stats/contributors. Still great to know the reason. Thank you so much.